# Unable to create GD image resource from BMP with MIME type 'image/x-ms-bmp' in PHP

Tags: php, gd, bmp

I'm trying to create a GD image resource from a BMP image, however I'm having no luck.

The BMP image in question was created and saved with Photoshop. I've tried a couple of BMPs I found on the web too, and they gave the same results.

getimagesize() tells me the BMP image has an image type of IMAGETYPE_BMP (6) and a MIME type of 'image/x-ms-bmp'.

I've tried running the image through imagecreatefromwbmp() and imagecreatefromxbm(), but neither recognise it. I've also tried running it through imagecreatefromstring(), but that errored saying 'Data is not in a recognized format'.

I'm running XAMPP on a Windows machine with PHP 5.3.1 and GD 2.0.34 with WBMP and XBM support enabled. I've also tried this on a Linux server running PHP 5.2.6 and GD 2.0.34 with WBMP and XBM support enabled, same result.

Any ideas how I can create a GD image resource from this BMP? Is it actually possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it doesn't support BMP images. The `imagecreatefromwbmp()` method is for dealing with wireless bitmaps (WBMP) files, not the normal BMP you have there. The `imagecreatefromxbm()` is for dealing with the XBM format (again, different from BMP).

I would work around this by re-opening Photoshop and re-saving as PNG or JPG. Assuming you have PHP installed/compiled with the appropriate support, you'll be able to work with one or both of those image formats fine.

Comment: It's probably faster to use `convert` from ImageMagick if you have more than a couple of images to convert.

Comment: I knew I was missing something as simple as that. I simply assumed WBMP was Windows Bitmap or something. Thank you.

Comment: It’s 2023 and since PHP 7.2, we have imagecreatefrombmp() - it works great.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new opensource project on Github that allows reading and saving of BMP files (and other file formats) in PHP. It's pretty easy to use.

The project is called [PHP Image Magician](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com).

Answer (score 1):

The solution you are looking for is here: 
http://tr.php.net/imagecreate

Scroll below to the comments to find the function named "**ImageCreateFromBMP**".
It will help you create images from the bmp images.

Once you create the image you can use the **imagejpeg()** function to save the image in jpeg format.

Comment: Perfect. Working solution right from the source (official PHP web site). Works just fine for me

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7.2 introduced support for BMP in GD library: [imagebmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagebmp.php), [imagecreatefrombmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrombmp.php).

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall learning a long time ago that GD doesn't support BMP format.

[Here's](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/3033-there-bmp-support-gd) a link I just found.

Although there was some confusion about WBMP files, it was a long time ago.

[This timeline](http://delicious.com/search?p=gd+bmp+support&chk=&context=recent|&fr=del_icio_us&lc=) from Delicious.com indicates it was probably 2005.

Answer (score 0):

use function :

```
function imagecreatefrombmp( $filename )
{
    $file = fopen( $filename, "rb" );
    $read = fread( $file, 10 );
    while( !feof( $file ) && $read != "" )
    {
        $read .= fread( $file, 1024 );
    }
    $temp = unpack( "H*", $read );
    $hex = $temp[1];
    $header = substr( $hex, 0, 104 );
    $body = str_split( substr( $hex, 108 ), 6 );
    if( substr( $header, 0, 4 ) == "424d" )
    {
        $header = substr( $header, 4 );
        // Remove some stuff?
        $header = substr( $header, 32 );
        // Get the width
        $width = hexdec( substr( $header, 0, 2 ) );
        // Remove some stuff?
        $header = substr( $header, 8 );
        // Get the height
        $height = hexdec( substr( $header, 0, 2 ) );
        unset( $header );
    }
    $x = 0;
    $y = 1;
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
    foreach( $body as $rgb )
    {
        $r = hexdec( substr( $rgb, 4, 2 ) );
        $g = hexdec( substr( $rgb, 2, 2 ) );
        $b = hexdec( substr( $rgb, 0, 2 ) );
        $color = imagecolorallocate( $image, $r, $g, $b );
        imagesetpixel( $image, $x, $height-$y, $color );
        $x++;
        if( $x >= $width )
        {
            $x = 0;
            $y++;
        }
    }
    return $image;
}
```

source 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatefromwbmp.php