# opening image with Imagine gives 'An image could not be created from the given input'

Tags: php, gd, php-imagine

I'm using [Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) to resize images after uploading them with curl in `/tmp`:

```
$_imagine = new \Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
$mode = \Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET;
$image = $_imagine->open($path); // i.e $path = '/tmp/photo.jpg'
// then resizing the $image
```

It is working fine with any previously uploaded images in my `/tmp`, but when uploading this image http://newsimg.bbc.co.uk/media/images/67373000/jpg/_67373987_09f1654a-e583-4b5f-bfc4-f05850c6d3ce.jpg then trying to open it with Imagine, it gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Imagine\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'An image could not be created from the given input'

**Did anybody know what is wrong with this image that makes it throw this exception?**

---

here is the `print_r(getimagesize($path));` as asked by @hakre:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 464
    [1] => 261
    [2] => 6
    [3] => width="464" height="261"
    [bits] => 32
    [mime] => image/x-ms-bmp
)
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Which Imagine version are you using? Which GD version are you using? Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: latest. You think could it be that the uploading code (using curl) changes something in the image?

Comment: When asking for more details - and so that it makes sense for other users naturally (*always* have those in mind) - please provide concrete version numbers for the softwares I asked for. Just saying you're using *"latest"* is of *no use* at all.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is triggered by using the `open()` method?

Comment: yes it is in `open()` method

Comment: Hmm, Please tell the filename and line of code where the exception is thrown. Also please add the backtrace. Because as far as I can see, inside the `open()` method that exception is not thrown. So I'm puzzled how the code inside the `load()` method is triggered via `open()`.

Comment: Open() calls read() which calls load() !

Comment: if that's how it gets invoked, see my answer. it's a format that is not supported.The problem I can see with the resource you're trying to open is that the HTTP response headers mismatch the file-type.

Comment: can you also add the output of `print_r(getimagesize($path));` to your question?

Comment: similar to this question here, i would try ImageMagick / GMagick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100875/unable-to-create-gd-image-resource-from-bmp-with-mime-type-image-x-ms-bmp-in-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to this question answered here:
[Unable to create GD image resource from BMP with MIME type 'image/x-ms-bmp' in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100875/unable-to-create-gd-image-resource-from-bmp-with-mime-type-image-x-ms-bmp-in-p)

To put shortly, this is a BMP image, and GD can't handle it as it seems from this answer, i would try ImageMagick / GMagick

Comment: you are right, instantiating the Imagine instance like this `$_imagine = new \Imagine\Gmagick\Imagine();` solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into the source-code you can directly find the explanation. That Imagine class uses the underlying GD image library of PHP to open images.

The `Imagine\Exception\InvalidArgumentException` exception message

> An image could not be created from the given input

just means that the [`imagecreatefromstring()`](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring) function failed.

However, for the current Imagine version this exception should not be triggered on [`\Imagine\Gd\Imagine::open()`](https://github.com/romainneutron/Imagine/blob/master/lib/Imagine/Gd/Imagine.php#L113). So you're probably using a different version.

Comment: I've tried the latest but with the same result with this image

Comment: What you consider to be *"the latest"* might be different to what I named *"the current Imagine version"*. I meant *master* as of 20 minutes ago on Github - see as well the link I've left. Also in a week, users visiting this question will have problems as well to determine the exact Imagine, GD and PHP version for what you just called "latest". Nobody will be able to decipher that information.

Comment: ok, it was 'master' branch 15 min ago for Imagine, and I'm using PHP 5.4

Comment: Please also get GD version: http://php.net/gd_info - An please say which PHP version exactly (some functions used by Imagine not only depend on GD but also on PHP so the exact version is *very* useful). Your exact version numbers are required to know because that file is served with a mismatch between the HTTP response mime-type, the common used file-extension in the URI and the magic numbers in the raw binary data: http://goo.gl/V74tc