# Error while loading fixtures during Sonata Sandbox Installation

Tags: php, symfony, sandbox, sonata

I'm trying to install Sonata Sandbox on my Mac with PHP5.5 with the following command line :

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=600 php composer.phar create-project sonata-project/sandbox:dev-2.3-develop
```

All works great until I load fixtures, I get the following error with LoadProductData :

```
loading [12] Sonata\Bundle\DemoBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadProductData

[Imagine\Exception\InvalidArgumentException] 
An image could not be created from the given input
```

Can anyone now how to fix this error ?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513472/opening-image-with-imagine-gives-an-image-could-not-be-created-from-the-given-i) and [this](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine/issues/233) links

Comment: same error, those links wouldn't help